# How do I get full-screen to maximize on just one window in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

Also asked @ launchpad: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+question/196690

On Kubuntu 11.10 and below, when I went full-screen (flash, game, whatever), the app full screen took up just one monitor.  But after upgrading to 12.04, it spans both screens, which is ugly on some computers and causes loss of viability on my others where the vertical resolution differs.

How do I fix this? I want full screen to take one monitor; not span across two.

This happens regardless of graphics cards; fails on both integrated intel cards and nvidia ones. I have three computers; all have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've been upgrading my 32bit Ubuntu ever since Lucid Lynx, was running 32bit Precise just fine. Now decided to switch to 64bit and performed a clean 64bit Precise install. After that, I'm experiencing the exact same issue. **I have managed to get all the applications to max just fine by unticking all the options in the "Multiple Monitor" part of the display settings, rebooting and reticking them.** However, the flash issue still remains.